# I have a issue.. Appending

Tags: ruby, numbers, append

I have this code:

```
  1 #!/local/usr/bin/ruby
  2 
  3 users = (1..255).to_a
  4 
  5 x = " "
  6 y = " "
  7 z = " "
  8 #a = " "
  9 
 10 count = 1
 11 users.each do |i|
 12   x << i if count == 1
 13   y << i if count == 2
 14   z << i if count == 3
 15  # if x.length == 60
 16  #   a << i if count == 1
 17  #   a << i if count == 2
 18  #   a << i if count == 3
 19  # else
 20  # end
 21   if count == 3
 22     count = 1
 23   else
 24     count += 1
 25   end
 26 end
 27 
 28 puts x.length
 29 puts y.length
 30 puts z.length
 31 #puts a.length
 32
```

What this code does is append The numbers 1-255 into three different strings and outputs how many numbers are in each string.

**IT WORKS**

Example of working code:

```
[user@server ruby]$ ruby loadtest.rb
86
86
86
[user@server ruby]$
```

Now what I want it to do is have a failsafe called `a` as seen above, commented out, What I want is this, if each string contains 60 numbers I want it to append into the `a` string until there are no more numbers.

When I try to do it with the commented out section it outputs this:

```
[user@server ruby]$ ruby loadtest.rb
86
86
86
4
[user@server ruby]$ ruby loadtest.rb
```

WHY?! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Program prints 86,86,86,4  not 86,86,86,256

Comment: @WandMaker Yeah I noticed that, I just edited the question.

Comment: It is doing what you have written code for, what is the expected output?

Comment: Please don't prepend line numbers to your code unless you are showing specific lines that are referred to by an error/exception. Your sample code should be easily copied/pasted and be the minimum necessary to demonstrate a problem. Anything beyond that slows people helping you.

Comment: Please don't include line numbers (or IRB prompts, etc.) with your code, as it prevents readers from simply cutting and pasting. If you need to reference a line you can do it without line numbers. Once you get your code working consider posting it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get suggestions for how it can be improved.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Code Review is for code that works _the way you want it to_ with out any bugs. This program obviously didn't work the way I wanted it to, so why post it somewhere it doesn't belong?

Comment: I said, "Once you get your code working...". Think of it as a two-step process. You first need to know what you've done wrong and how to fix it. That's what SO is for. Once you understand the problem and have working code it still may not use the power of Ruby effectively. To see how you could improve your (working) code, post it on Code Review. Members of CR are eager to help, including those new to Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... if each string contains 60 numbers I want it to append into the a string until there are no more numbers

As written, you are unconditionally appending to x,y,z even after they hit your limit.
You need to add a conditional around this code:

```
   x << i if count == 1
   y << i if count == 2
   z << i if count == 3
```

so that it stops appending once it hits your limit.

By the looks of the else block that does nothing, I think you were headed in that direction:

```
  if x.length == 60
    a << i if count == 1
    a << i if count == 2
    a << i if count == 3
  else
   x << i if count == 1
   y << i if count == 2
   z << i if count == 3
  end
```

Even that, though, won't do exactly what you want. 
You'll want to check the string you are appending to to see if it has hit your limit yet.

I'd suggest refactoring to make it cleaner:

```
 users.each do |i|
   target_string = case count
   when 1 then x
   when 2 then y
   when 3 then z
   end

   target_string = a if target_string.length == 60

   target_string << i

   if count == 3
     count = 1
   else
     count += 1
   end
 end
```

Comment: OOOO that is awesome, thanks for the great information!

Answer (score 2):

> What this code does is append The numbers 1-255 into three different strings and outputs how many numbers are in each string.

After reducing the number of values being iterated for readability, here's what it's doing:

```
users = (1..5).to_a

x = " "
y = " "
z = " "

count = 1
users.each do |i|
  x << i if count == 1 # => " \u0001", nil, nil, " \u0001\u0004", nil
  y << i if count == 2 # => nil, " \u0002", nil, nil, " \u0002\u0005"
  z << i if count == 3 # => nil, nil, " \u0003", nil, nil

  if count == 3
    count = 1
  else
    count += 1
  end
end

x # => " \u0001\u0004"
y # => " \u0002\u0005"
z # => " \u0003"

puts x.length
puts y.length
puts z.length

# >> 3
# >> 3
# >> 2
```

Your code is creating binary inside the strings, not "numbers" as we normally think of them, as digits.

Moving on, you can clean up your logic using `each_with_index` and `case`/`when`. To make the results more readable I switched from accumulating into strings into arrays:

```
users = (1..5).to_a

x = []
y = []
z = []

users.each_with_index do |i, count|
  case count % 3
  when 0
    x << i
  when 1
    y << i
  when 2
    z << i
  end
end

x # => [1, 4]
y # => [2, 5]
z # => [3]

puts x.length
puts y.length
puts z.length

# >> 2
# >> 2
# >> 1
```

The real trick in this is the use of [`%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Numeric.html#method-i-25), which does a modulo on the value.

Comment: Why is it placing `nil` inside of the strings instead of just binary from 0001 - 0005...?

Comment: It's not putting nil in the strings. Look at the values for `x`, `y` and `z`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to use an array instead of string as you are pushing numbers into those variables.

Let me propose a solution which achieves more or less what you are trying to do, but uses few Ruby tricks that may be useful in future.

```
x, y, z = r = Array.new(3) {[]}
a = []

iter = [0,1,2].cycle

(1..255).each do |i|
  r.all? {|i| i.size == 60} ? a << i : r[iter.next] << i
end

p x.size, y.size, z.size
p a.size
```

---

Let's define our arrays.  Even though I have arrays `x`, `y`, and `z`, they are there only because they were present in your code - I think we just need three arrays, each of which would collect numbers as they are picked from a range of numbers - between 1 to 255 - one by one.  `x,y,z = r` uses parallel assignment technique and is equivalent to `x,y,z = r[0],r[1],r[2]`.   Also, use of `Array.new(3) {[]}` helps in creating the Array of Array such that when we access `r[1]` it is initialized with empty array(`[]`) by default.

```
x, y, z = r = Array.new(3) {[]}
a = []
```

In order to determine which array the next number picked from range has to be placed in, we will use an Enumerator generated from [`Enumerable#cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle).  This enumerator is special - because it is soft of infinite in nature - and we can keep asking it to give an element by calling `next`, and it will cycle through the array elements of `[0,1,2]` - returning us `0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2...` infinitely.

```
iter = [0,1,2].cycle
```

Next, we will iterate through the range of numbers 1..255.  During each iteration, we will check whether all the 3 arrays in which we are collecting number have desired size of `60` with the help of [`Enumerable#all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) - if so, we will append the number to array `a` - else we will assign it to one of the sub arrays of `r` based on the array index returned by `iter` enumerator.

```
(1..255).each do |i|
  r.all? {|i| i.size == 60} ? a << i : r[iter.next] << i
end
```

Finally, we print the size of each of the array.

```
p x.size, y.size, z.size
#=> 60, 60, 60
p a.size
#=> 75
```

Comment: You might want to explain what `cycle` and `next` are doing.

Comment: @theTinMan Sure, let me try to explain